# SQL How to order by day and then by sum

Tags: mysql, sql

Each row of my table is an application (google, facebook) with the date and bytes.

What I'm doing is grouping by app and date with this request :

```
SELECT app, sum(bytes) as total, date
FROM logs
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2018-11-23' AND '2018-11-25'
GROUP BY app, date
```

This is the result :

```
app      | total  | date
facebook | 2736   | 2018-11-23
google   | 4968   | 2018-11-23
twitter  | 606520 | 2018-11-23
facebook | 2736   | 2018-11-24
youtube  | 153077 | 2018-11-24
twitter  | 84561  | 2018-11-24
```

But what I need is to order total in DESC. So now I'm trying for each day to order by total and have this result :

```
app      | total  | date
twitter  | 606520 | 2018-11-23 <---
google   | 4968   | 2018-11-23 <---
facebook | 2736   | 2018-11-23
youtube  | 153077 | 2018-11-24 <---
twitter  | 84561  | 2018-11-24 <---
facebook | 2736   | 2018-11-24
```

Any idea on how to do that with mysql ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below  using `order by total desc and date asc`

```
SELECT app, sum(bytes) as total, date
FROM logs
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2018-11-23' AND '2018-11-25'
GROUP BY app, date
order by date,total desc
```

Comment: This will return a totally different answer set. You have to switch the Oorder By colujmns

Comment: Well ... Easier than I thought ahah. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data suggests me :

```
SELECT app, sum(bytes) as total, date
FROM logs
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2018-11-23' AND '2018-11-25'
GROUP BY app, date
ORDER BY date, total DESC;
```